# What is best way to communicate parent class and its inner class in kotlin?

Tags: java, class, kotlin

In java if I am having a class and inside it I have another child class, than child class can access its parent class methods , but while same is giving error in kotlin for example

```java
class A {
    static int methodSum(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }

    static final class Try {
        void tryPrint() {
            System.Out.println(methodSum(2,3).toString())
        }
    }
}
```

But same I am not able to achieve in Kotlin its giving me error . what is the best way to achieve this .

Comment: not in this case, since the inner class is market as static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Nested and Inner Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) in Kotlin docs.
When you use 'Inner Class' the class will always hold a reference to an object of the outer class.

```
class Outer {
    private val bar: Int = 1
    inner class Inner {
        fun getOuter() = this@Outer
        fun foo() = bar
    }
}

val outerObj = Outer().Inner().getOuter()
val bar = Outer().Inner().foo()
```

**Update:** since gidds explained this perfectly in his comment:

> To clarify: like Java, Kotlin offers both inner classes (which have a reference to an instance of the outer class), and nested classes (which don't). But they differ in their default: Java assumes an inner class unless you use static to mark it as nested; while Kotlin assumes a nested class unless you mark it with inner.

Comment: To clarify: like Java, Kotlin offers both inner classes (which have a reference to an instance of the outer class), and nested classes (which don't).  But they differ in their default: Java assumes an inner class unless you use `static` to mark it as nested; while Kotlin assumes a nested class unless you mark it with `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

use  internal class like this

```
internal object A {

fun methodSum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {

    return a + b
}

internal class Try {

    fun tryPrint() {
         println(methodSum(2, 3).toString())
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: okay So  you are saying . I should made my outer class as object and rest as java ?

Comment: yes.more detail refer https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html